# Django Forms and 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rsplit' error

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I've seriously waisted a couple days trying to figure this out and have absolutely run into a brick wall. I've researched and read all the SO posts on this issue, but could finally use some help please.

I am trying to hook up a simple contact form and below is the latest rendition of my code that throws the same `'tuple' object has no attribute 'rsplit' error` when I submit the form.

*My Django version is 1.9 and using Python3.5*

```
def contact(request):
    title = 'Contact Us'
    title_align_center = True
    form = ContactForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid():
        form_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
        form_message = form.cleaned_data.get('message')
        form_full_name = form.cleaned_data.get('full_name')
        subject = 'Site Contact Form'
        from_email = settings.DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL
        recipient_list = [from_email, 'charles@studiorooster.com']
        message = '%s: %s via %s' % (
            form_full_name,
            form_message,
            form_email)
        # some_html_message = ''' <h1>hello</h1> '''

        email = EmailMessage(
            subject,
            message,
            form_email,
            recipient_list,
            ['roosteromg@gmail.com'],
            reply_to=[from_email],
            headers={'Reply-To': from_email},
        )
        email.send()

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'title': title,
        'title_align_center': title_align_center,
    }
    return render(request, 'pages/contact.html', context)
```

**Traceback**

```
Environment:

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8001/contact/

Django Version: 1.9
Python Version: 3.5.1
Installed Applications:
['accounts',
 'comments',
 'pages',
 'posts',
 'search',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django_summernote']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "/Users/rooster/Documents/Development/boston_intercom/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  149.                     response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "/Users/rooster/Documents/Development/boston_intercom/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  147.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "/Users/rooster/Documents/Development/boston_intercom/pages/views.py" in contact
  80.         email.send()

File "/Users/rooster/Documents/Development/boston_intercom/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in send
  292.         return self.get_connection(fail_silently).send_messages([self])

File "/Users/rooster/Documents/Development/boston_intercom/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/message.py" in get_connection
  250.             self.connection = get_connection(fail_silently=fail_silently)

File "/Users/rooster/Documents/Development/boston_intercom/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/mail/__init__.py" in get_connection
  36.     klass = import_string(backend or settings.EMAIL_BACKEND)

File "/Users/rooster/Documents/Development/boston_intercom/venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/utils/module_loading.py" in import_string
  15.         module_path, class_name = dotted_path.rsplit('.', 1)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /contact/
Exception Value: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rsplit'
```

Comment: Please paste the complete traceback so that I can rectify the cause of errors.

Comment: Show the structure of default  email settings in settings.py file.There is some problem with those settings,that's why the error is coming.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then The problem is in your settings.py file with default mail settings,as you can see in the traceback, **EMAIL_BACKEND** setting might be the problem.

Those settings should be like this :

```
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'youremail@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'yourpassword'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL =  'youremail@gmail.com'
```